# How to delay the java script keyup() handler when user clear text field

Tags: javascript, php, keyup, onkeyup

I'm using JavaScript `keyup()` event for a single text box.

If someone types “Windows”, it will send an HTTP request for every keyup:

> “W”, “Wi”, “Win”, “Wind”, “Windo”, “Window”, “Windows”

This is the desired behaviour.

When the user clears the text box empty, it gives an error.

This is the undesired behaviour.

**Question**

How can I stop an HTTP request being sent when the text box is cleared?

Comment: show your code. You can check text length of user inupt then begin search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX to send information to the server (and get information for that matter):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  echo json_encode($_POST);
  die();
}

?>

<form>
  <input id="search" type="text" name="search" />
</form>

<script>

document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", "#", true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        object = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(object);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send("search=" + this.value);
});

</script>
```

Comment: @LasanthaHerath Awesome!  If you could mark as solution it'd help a lot, have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `value` before making request

```js
function getResult(elem) {

  if (elem.value !== '') {

    console.log('Have values')
  } else {

    console.log('No values')
  }


}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="getResult(this)">
```